# Vertically splitting the text with a use of single DOM

Tags: html, css

I need to split my text vertically, with line breaks. That is only one word should be present in a single line. Actually i achieved by using separate `DIV` for each word. Is there is any possibility of achieving the same using a single `div`. Refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzy50qyc/) for what i'm actually looking for. Hope you understand my question. Please feel free to edit my post if my english is bad.

```
<div>
  <div> s </div>
   <div>u </div> 
  <div> n </div>
</div>

div > div{
  text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Is java script or jQuery an option ?

Comment: @Pugazh javascript i can make by splitting the text and  placing it in a seperate DOM.  Through css is there is any possibilities

Answer (score 3):

Yes, below CSS hack can do.

Have a width smaller than the text size and use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the letters.

**CSS Only solution:**

```css
div {
  /* width should not be lesser than font size */
  width: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Sun
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

example in fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zzy50qyc/4/

you should use `<br>` tag to brake line

or `<pre>` tag to adjust your text like you want

Comment: hell its...Nice one dude...But my content will be dynamic so i don't want to add br tag at the end of each word in javascript. But anyway this closer and efficient solution which i can use. Thanks

Comment: Pre tag will be a bad idea for my functionality, Since i have to do so with user input text

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the width of the parent div to 1px and enter all your text in the parent div. Like so:`<div>sun</div>`
and have your style class as so:
`<style>div {width: 1px;word-wrap: break-word;}</style>`

Sorry about the formatting, but I think you get the gist.